# Passing anonymous types in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am using ASP.net MVC with C#.  Why this is code:

```
public IQueryable<Product> ListProducts(string prodcutType)
{
    var results = from p in db.Products
        join s in db.Stocks
        on p.ID equals s.IDProduct
        where p.ptype == prodcutType
        select new { s.width, s.height, s.number};                 
    return results;
}
```

showing the following error?

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>`
>   to
>   `System.Linq.IQueryable<eim.Models.Product>`.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `select new { s.width, s.height, s.number}` means `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>` but your function expects to return `IQueryable<Product>`. Change your code to:

```
public IQueryable<Product> ListProducts(string prodcutType)
{

    var results = from p in db.Products
                  join s in db.Stocks
                  on p.ID equals s.IDProduct
                  where p.ptype == prodcutType
                  select p;
    return results;
}
```

**UPDATED:**

Or maybe you want `IQueryable<Stock>`:

```
public IQueryable<Stock> ListProducts(string prodcutType)
{

    var results = from p in db.Products
                  join s in db.Stocks
                  on p.ID equals s.IDProduct
                  where p.ptype == prodcutType
                  select s;
    return results;
}
```

If you want only 3 properties width+height+number create new type. For example:

```
public class SomeType {
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<SomeType> ListProducts(string prodcutType)
{

    var results = from p in db.Products
                  join s in db.Stocks
                  on p.ID equals s.IDProduct
                  where p.ptype == prodcutType
                  select new SomeType {
                      Width = s.width,
                      Height = s.height,
                      Number = s.number
                  };
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last line of your LINQ query

```
select new { s.width, s.height, s.number};
```

will select only these three fields from your table "db.Stocks", and this creates a new, anonymous type, which is what gets stored in "results" and passed back.

What you're passing back in the "return results;" statement therefore **isn't** a `IQueryable<Product>` - it's something totally different (that IQueryable of an anonymous type).

If you want to return products, you'll need to cast that anonymous type to a "Product" (or create a new product class from the fields selected).

Marc